# Help calculate the probablility of multiple second place lottery winners

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm trying to calculate the probability of multiple second place lottery winners. For example, on January 13th there were 10 second place winners (https://www.beatlottery.net/powerball/results/draw_date/2021-01-13). Is having ten second place winners more or less likely than having one jackpot winner?

For reference, I am referring to the Powerball lottery (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerball)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer. :)

> Is having ten second place winners more or less likely than having one
> jackpot winner?

Going from the wikipedia on the US Powerball Odds from here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerball#Prizes_and_odds

The chance of getting first place, i.e. 5 numbers plus the Powerball, is
1 in 292,201,338.

The chance of getting second place, i.e. five numbers without the Powerball, is
1 in 11,688,053.52.

So, and I'm no mathematician, by the way...
I'd hazard a guess that the chance of 10 people getting 2nd division would be more likely than 1 person getting first division...

eg. 1 in 11,688,053.52 x 10 = 1 in 116,880,535.20.

and I'd take that further and say its more likely that 20+ people would get 2nd division than 1 person getting first division...
ie. above x2...or 1 in 233,761,070.40, which is still better than the chance of 1 person winning 1st division.

If you are trying to estimate the actual number of 2nd place winners, you'd need to know, for a given draw, the number of entrants....and then divide that number by the chance of them winning 2nd place.

Obviously, for each 11,688,053.52 entrants, there would be on average 1 2nd Place winner - assuming that each entrant only bet on one group of 6 numbers, of course, which is probably not the case.

Comment: Can you explain why you divided  1 in 11,688,053.52 by 10?

Comment: Hi again KAnders.
I didn't divide it by 10, I multiplied it by 10...If the chance of any one person/entry/guesses of getting second place was 1 in 11,688,053.52, then the chance of 10 same people/entry/guesses ALL getting second place is 10 times that figure, eg, 1 in 116,880,535.20.
Like I said, I'm no mathematician...so I could be wrong. :)